# Execute "system.exe","-get t"

Tags: java, windows, command

Please help me I used this java code :

```
public class ClientApplication {    
    public static void main(String[] args) {            
        String[] commands = new String[] {"system.exe","-get t"};    
        try{
        Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
        Process proc = rt.exec(commands);
            BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new 
             InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));
            BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new 
             InputStreamReader(proc.getErrorStream()));
        System.out.println("Here is the standard output of the command:\n");
        String s = null;
        while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
System.out.println("Here is the standard error of the command (if any):\n");
        while ((s = stdError.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
        } catch (Exception e)   {e.setStackTrace(null);}}}
```

to get information about the system but an exception is detected :

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException.

Please can you help me to execute a command in windows device.

Comment: I search how execute command in windows 7

Comment: What line is the exception thrown from?

Comment: in the Process proc = rt.exec(commands); line

Comment: So did you try to figure out why `rt` is null?

Comment: No rt is not null

Comment: rt return java.lang.Runtime@addbf1 in the execution but the command is not executed

Comment: You said that the `NullPointerException` is thrown from `Process proc = rt.exec(commands);`. Now you're saying it's not. So I'm asking again - where is the exception thrown from?

Comment: The error is in system.exe does not exist in windows 7

Comment: Yes the error is in this line but the problem is in the command

Comment: `NullPointerException` is thrown when you're executing some method on an object which is `null`. What's the `null` object?

Comment: the command "system.exe" is null

Comment: I search a command to get the executing process in windows device? I used this command "system.exe" but it return null

Comment: Dude, a *command* cannot be null. A *variable* or *object* can be null. So I guess the variable `proc` is null?

Comment: yes proc is null

Comment: Great. So now you have a much better question, a focused one, and you can try to figure that out. You can find a better Windows experts than me, but I think `system.exe` is a system file. It might already be running, it might need different permissions, it might only run in kernel-space. My point is - try to use a simple, small user program, that you can execute yourself using windows command line. Verify it's actually executing from there, and then test your code with it.

Comment: yes I test it thanks SHG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not a Windows expert, but my understanding is that "system.exe" is not a Windows command.  So trying to *use* it as a command like this will not work.

This doesn't explain the NPE, but I am not convinced that the information you have given us about where the NPE is occurring is accurate.  But I can tell you that the only way that there is no way that an NPE can be thrown at `THIS LINE` in the following:

```
    String[] commands = new String[] {"system.exe","-get t"};    
    Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
    Process proc = rt.exec(commands);  // THIS LINE
```

The value of `rt` cannot be `null`, the `command` variable is not `null` and the array doesn't contain any `null` values.

In short, either the NPE occurred at a different line, or the code you are running is different to what you have shown us.

Unfortunately ( from your perspective ) I don't have a Windows machine that I can use to experiment with your code.

---

Finally, this is completely wrong:

```
    } catch (Exception e)   {e.setStackTrace(null);}}}
```

And ... now that I think about what is inside the try block ... this is probably the **real place** where the NPE is being thrown!  The javadoc for `setStackTrace` says:

> Throws: `NullPointerException` - if `stackTrace` is `null` or if any of the elements of `stackTrace` are `null`.

OTOH, it makes no sense to `setStackTrace` there anyway.   What are you trying to achieve?